# core dumps in Mac OS X

Tags: bash

I was wondering if core dumps are disabled by default in Mac OS X, or if we have to add the following line to our `.bash_profile`:

```
ulimit -S -c 0
```

Comment: What is Your output of: `sysctl -a | grep coredump` ?

Comment: `$ sysctl -a | grep coredump
kern.coredump = 1
kern.sugid_coredump = 0
kern.coredump: 1
kern.sugid_coredump: 0`

Answer (score 2):

By default, ulimits on OS X have a soft limit of 0 and a hard limit of unlimited.

You can verify this by opening a Terminal and running `ulimit -S -c` and `ulimit -H -c`.